# Separate class ownership and use, generate optimal (fast) code

Tags: c++, design-patterns, template-meta-programming

In general, my question was simple, I want to imlement some design pattern, which allows following:

1. there is exists some predefined interface (`Interface` class);
2. and exists class (`Utilizer`), which accepts another class (via pointer, reference, smart-pointer, whatever else...) implementing predefined interface, and stars using this class via the interface;
3. class `Utilizer` should be able to own other class passed to it (which implements `Interface`) and delete it when `Utilizer` is destroyed.

In managed languages (like C#, Java) this can be implemented in simple way: class `Utilizer` might accept reference to base class (`Interface`) and hold this reference in the class, and use interface via the reference. On destruction of `Utilizer` class, the garbage collector might delete class, which implements `Interface'.

In C++ we have no garbage collector... Ok, we can use some smart_pointer, but this might be not generic smart pointer, but smart pointer of some particular type (for example, unique_ptr with user specified deleter, because class, which implements `Interface` is resided in shared memory and regular operator delete() can't be applied to this class...)

And second nuisance: virtual functions. Of course, when you are using managed languages you may not notice this. But if you made `Interface` class as abstract base class (with virtual keyword), then you will notice, that in `test` function (see the code below) compiler performs indirect calls (via function pointers). This happens because compiler needs to access virtual functions table. The call via function pointer is not very heavy (few processor ticks, or event tens of ticks), but the major issue is that compiler doesn't see that happens next, after the indirection. Optimizer stops here. Functions can't be inlined anymore. And we get not optimal code, which doesn't reduces to few machine instructions (for example `test` function reduces in the example to loading of two constant and calling `printf` function), we get unoptimal "generic" implementation, which effectively nullifies all the benefits of C++.

There is typical solution to avoid getting of unoptimal code -- avoid using virtual functions (prefer CRTP pattern instead), avoid type erasure (in the example, `Utilizer` class might store not `Accessor`, but `std::function<Interface<T>&()>` -- this solution is nice, but indirection in std::function leads to generation of unoptimal code again).

And the essence of the question, how to implement the logic described above (class which owns other *abstract*, non some particular, class and uses it) in C++ effectively?

Not sure if I was able to clearly express my thought. Below is the my implementation with the comments. It generates optimal code (see disassembly of `test` function in live demo [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acccd7fcc2660a36)), all is inlined as expected. But the whole implementation looks cumbersome.

I would like to hear how can I improve the code.

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// This type implements interface: later Utilizer class
// accept Accessor type, which was able to return reference
// to object of some type, which implements this interface,
// and Utilizer class uses returned object via this interface.
template <typename Impl> class Interface
{
public:
    int oper(int arg) { return static_cast<Impl*>(this)->oper(arg); }

    const char *name() const { return static_cast<const Impl*>(this)->name(); }
};

// Class which uses object, returned by Accessor class, via
// predefined interface of type Interface<Impl>.
// Utilizer class can perform operations on any class
// which inherited from Interface class, but Utilizer
// doesn't directly owns parficular instance of the 
// class implementing Interface: Accessor serves for
// getting of particular implementation of Interface
// from somewhere.
template <typename Accessor> class Utilizer
{
private:
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<Accessor>()())>::type Impl;
    Accessor accessor;

    // This static_cast allows only such Accessor types, for
    // which operator() returns class inherited from Interface
    Interface<Impl>& get() const { return static_cast<Interface<Impl>&>(accessor()); }

public:
    template <typename...Args> Utilizer(Args&& ...args) : accessor(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    // Following functions is the public interface of Utilizer class
    // (this interface have no relations with Interface class,
    // except of the fact, that implementation uses Interface class):

    double func(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > 0) return sqrt(get().oper(a) + b);
        else return get().oper(b) * a;
    }

    const char *text() const
    {
        const char *result = get().name();
        if (result == nullptr) return "unknown";
        return result;
    }
};

// This is implementation of Interface<Impl> interface
// (program may have multiple similar classes and Utilizer
// can work with any of these classes).
struct Implementation : public Interface<Implementation>
{
    Implementation() { puts("Implementation()"); }

    Implementation(const Implementation&) { puts("copy Implementation"); }

    ~Implementation() { puts("~Implementation()"); }

    // Following functions are implementation of functions
    // defined in Interface<Impl>:

    int oper(int arg) { return arg + 42; }

    const char *name() const { return "implementation"; }
};

// This is class which owns some particular implementation
// of the class inherited from Interface. This class only
// owns the class which was given to it and allows accessing
// this class via operator(). This class is intendent to be
// template argument for Utilizer class.
template <typename SmartPointer> struct Owner
{
    SmartPointer p;
    Owner(Owner&& other) : p(std::move(other.p)) {}
    template <typename... Args> Owner(Args&&...args) : p(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    Implementation& operator()() const { return *p; }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Implementation> PtrType;

typedef Utilizer<Owner<PtrType> > UtilType;


void test(UtilType& utilizer)
{
    printf("%f %s\n", utilizer.func(1, 2), utilizer.text());
}


int main()
{
    PtrType t(new Implementation);
    UtilType utilizer(std::move(t));
    test(utilizer);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You may want to read the blog post [Polymorphic ducks](https://mropert.github.io/2017/11/30/polymorphic_ducks/) by Mathieu Ropert.  It goes through the exercise step-by-step to convert from using `virtual` and dynamic polymorphism to CRTP and compile time static polymorphism using TEPS.

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU is smarter than you think. Modern CPUs are absolutely capable of guessing the target of, and speculatively executing through, an indirect branch. The speed of the L1 cache, and register renaming, often remove most or all of the extra cost of a non-inlined call. And the 80/20 rule applies in spades: Your test code's bottleneck is the internal processing done by `puts`, not the late binding you're trying to avoid.

To answer your question, you could improve your code by removing all that template stuff: it would be just as fast, and more maintainable (hence more practical to do *actual* optimization). Optimization of algorithms and data structures should often be done up-front; optimization of low-level instruction streams should never, ever, *ever* be done except after analyzing profiling results.

Comment: You make too many assumptions: i might have bleeding edge CPU, but I can have Z80 instead, i might use only this particular (`Implementation`) class, but I might want to have ten of different classes and don't want to rewrite `Utilizer` for using each different class. And you think I want to improve overall performance. No, I understooding, that some particular, concrete solution might be better in particular case, but I want not to optimizer performance, but I want to learn to use **universal** **solutions** in that way, in which they will be as effective as "handcrafted" particular solution.

Comment: Also I suggest to read this article: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c -- it shows, that performance drop due to "virtual dispatcherization" might be huge (6 times). Actually the performance drop was caused not by the virtual dispatcheriztion itself (I noted, that it takes just few CPU cycles), but by the fact, that compiler can't perform effective code optimization, because compiler have no assumptions that happens after indirect function call.

And of course optimization isn't  for  `puts` call. This is JUST EXAMPLE.

Comment: If you want a universal solution which encompasses the Z80, that universal solution is going to have to be "don't use C++". :-) The "6 times" takeaway from that web page demonstrates the same mistake you've made with the code you've posted: Approaching optimization reductively rather than holistically. When it comes to optimization, you cannot generalize from toy examples to actual use cases; the concerns simply do not scale uniformly.